Unable to implement Elasticsearch hybrid count on python
I'm using Python 3.9 and I'm able to do hybrid search (query and knn) on Elasticsearch index. I'm Also able to do simple count either query or knn. but when I try to do hybrid count (query and knn) it does not work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below are the different approach that I used.
    # Count documents matching a query
query = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                       "title": sentence
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "knn": {
                        "field" : "titleVector",
                        "query_vector" : embedding_vector,
                        "similarity":1,
                        "k":7000,
                        "num_candidates":10000
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

response = es.count(
    index="rktb_framework",
    body = query
)
print(response)


The knn query doesn't support the parameter k. So, start with removing it.  If you still get an error, please post update your question with its content.

Please, could share the source of your information? because if you go here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html, you will noticed that knn support k parameter to return the top k nearest documents. And as I said before, use separately, my python code works I don't have issue with knn search

You are mixing two slightly different things. The link that you posted describes knn search. Notice how knn appears as a top level element of the search request. What you are trying to use in your example is knn query which is used inside a query element of the request and can be combined with other queries as in your example. If you check the first note on the knn query documentation page you will find a confirmation of my answer.

I am just curious why you didn't mark the answer as accepted then.

Hi Imotov, I thank you for your comment, that is why I gave you 1 point, because I learnt something. But I'm still looking at a solution to easily count the result of an hybrid search.

What does this number represent for you?
